# Change css value between two styles on click of same button using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an image upon which I want to bring a text on clicking the image. I applied the css display property to none and on click I changed it to block. Now again on clicking I want to change the display to none. How can I do that?

js:-

```
function showTerms(data){
    document.getElementById(data).style.display = 'block';
}
```

html:-

```
<div style="display: none;" id="text1111" class="offer_text size-12">
    <div class="TC">
        <div class="condition">Terms &amp; Condition</div>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <div><br></div>
    <div>- The coupon code is valid for one time use per user account.<br></div>
    <p></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a toggle function, like so:

```
function toggleTerms(data){
    document.getElementById(data).style.display = (document.getElementById(data).style.display == 'block' ? 'none': 'block'); 
}
```

Comment: Its not changing again to none

Comment: Actually on click the text is on the image. In your demo its above the image so I guess its not able to get the id of image

Comment: try to change the z-index.

Comment: @KshitijPandey, provide your complete HTML/CSS... Why do you need image id at all? However, code in answer must work, for sure....

Comment: I have a coupon image which on clicking should give terms and conditions

Comment: @AkashAmin z index??

Comment: document.getElementById(data).style.zIndex = "100"; This can work if have the div overlapping each other.

Comment: You will have to post your html css and js, you have a class "offer_text size-12." Without that no one might be able to help.

Comment: size-12 is just giving a font size of 12

Comment: what is your code to overlap the image on the div of text you want to display on the image. I think there must be a css for it.@KshitijPandey

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, do *not* modify CSS directly in JavaScript (there are of course exceptions, but in this case you shouldn't).

Instead, define a CSS class like so:

```
.shown {display: block}
```

Then your JavaScript can be as simple as:

```
function showTerms(data) {
    document.getElementById(data).classList.toggle("shown");
}
```

<sub>* If support for old browsers is needed, you'll need something a little more advanced to check if the class is on and toggle it manually.</sub>

Comment: @KshitijPandey Ah, remove the inline `display:none` and put that in CSS too, otherwise it continues to override.

Comment: If I am changing the inline css the text is already appearing on the image which I want to do it by clicking the image